# Autogenerate fields for 'point' layer to represent the lines 'ingress' and 'egress' from point

Tags: qgis, sql, fields-attributes

I have a point layer named `closure` and a line layer named `cable` in QGIS.

Within `closure` there's 4 fields (`id`, `type`, `ingress`, `egress`),
cable has 4 fields (`id`, `type`, `from`, `to`).

I have managed to form a code within attribute form to tell me that cable starts at `closure` Point A (`from` will show me `closure` `type`):

```
aggregate(layer:='closures_v1', aggregate:='max', expression:="type",
filter:= intersects( $geometry, start_point(geometry(@parent))))
```

and ends at closure Point B (to will show me `closure` `type`):

```
aggregate(layer:='closures_v1', aggregate:='max', expression:="type",
filter:= intersects( $geometry, end_point(geometry(@parent))))
```

Though I have not been able to autogenerate the fields for the `closure` layers' columns `ingress` and `egress`. `ingress` will represent the `cable` that is entering the `closure` (there can only be one), `egress` will represent the `cable` that is exiting the `closure` (there can be multiple). The autogenerated field will tell me the `cable` `type`.

Is this possible?

Let’s says I had one `closure` point called 'main closure', I will draw a `cable` (whatever I decide to label it, in this called 'cable IN') to end at the 'main closure' --- this will be my `ingress` cable.

Then, I draw two `cable`s starting from the 'main closure'(I will label these 'cable out1' and 'cable out2').

I would like an automated process to auto-fill my `ingress` layer to tell me that 'cable IN' is the `cable` entering the 'main closure', and my `egress` layer to tell me that 'cable out1' and 'cable out2' are exiting 'main closure'.

[image]

Comment: Please explain your workflow more detailed. What are you trying to do when, based on which layer?

Comment: You mention code but have not presented any.

Comment: A picture would really help explain this problem

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, I hope I understood it well. You mention a layer `closure`, but in your expression, it is named `closures_v1` - this adds to the confusion, as well that you don't tell us which of the attribute fields contains the name (like `cable in`). So we have to make a lot of assumptions. When asking a question, you should always be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To get the name (saved in field `type`) of the feature from the layer `cable` that enters the current point, use the expression below the screenshot. Use a virtual field to autogenerate the values. Like this, the value is updated automatically each time you change something.

*Screenshot: the expression, used here as source of a dynamic label:*
[image]

```
array_filter (
    array_foreach(
        overlay_nearest ('cable', $id, limit:=-1),
        if (
            intersects (
                end_point (geometry (get_feature_by_id('cable',@element))),
                buffer ($geometry,0.01)
            ),
            attribute (get_feature_by_id ('cable',@element), 'type'),
            ''
        )
    ),
    @element <>''
)[0]
```

To get the name of the outgoing cables, replace `end_point` in line 6 with `start_point` and enclose the whole expression as argument in a `array_to_string()` function, pseudocode: `array_to_string( [expression_from_above_changed_to_start_point])`